# Ruby navigation in Emacs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, emacs, ide, textmate

I am trying to use emacs for my rails project. I am kind of fed up with the etag navigation, Its really dumb. So is there any other way to do source code navigation for ruby in emacs?

Note: I also use rinari minor mode. Which is kind of intelligent to move between models, views ...
But what i want is some kind of jump to definition kind of stuff that you can see in regular IDEs. Please dont suggest me any IDEs as i am pretty satisfied with Emacs for everything else but this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ECB, or Emacs Code Browser (http://ecb.sourceforge.net/), is great for this. I use it for Rails Development; on activation, by default, you'll get a three panel window with folder structure, file list, and method browser.

For jumping to specific method definitions, check out the [TextMate Minor Mode](http://ozmm.org/posts/textmate_minor_mode.html). the command s-T will get you a dialogue that jumps you to the specified method, matching as you type.

Comment: Ya i have that too. But what i want is jump to definition. Not viewing the methods/classes declared in the specific file I mean similar to etags but little more intelligent

Comment: Thanks but how to index my files? It always No items found in index for the symbol...

Comment: the command `textmate-clear-cache` should do it. On my setup, it's bound to `M-s-T`. Run that, and try s-T again.. you should see the full list!

Answer (score 3):

For more advanced "jump to definition", check out [robe](https://github.com/dgutov/robe).

Comment: Robe looks interesting... It looks like it depends on inf-ruby though? What's the best way to go about loading a rails project into inf-ruby?

Comment: Install `rinari` and type `M-x rinari-console`. The "Usage" section inside the file mentions it.

Comment: rinari and rhtml combo works best. They can also work with ecb too.

Comment: `rhtml-mode` is one big hack. I prefer the solution I wrote myself using `mmm-mode`. Also a hack, but less invasive one.

Answer (score 0):

Best Emacs and Rails combination mode is rinari-mode http://rinari.rubyforge.org/
and rhtml-mode

It is available on melpa. Just run

```
M-x list-packages
```

And select rinari-mode and rhtml-mode

rinari-mode has advance navigation system. it also supports etags http://rinari.rubyforge.org/Navigation.html#Navigation

```
(setq rinari-tags-file-name "TAGS")
```